# RewriteCond for urls without query_string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

If catching urls with any query_string, this could be done with something like `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*` How can i build a condition for urls, which don't contain `query_string` at all?

I was trying `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*` and `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""`  - with no luck.

**Update**
The final task is to catch

- a. urls with some special parameters
- b. urls without parameters

I thought about a construction like proposed by @[arko444](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3115685/arco444) :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^param=(one|two)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteRule .* - [E=INDEX_HEADER:1] 
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Robots-Tag "index, follow" env=INDEX_HEADER
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What doesn't work with this construction? It's valid syntax and should do what you want

Comment: it seems not to catch urls without parameters - i don't see this tag in response header. URLs with defined parameters get the tag correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by `tag`? Are you trying to also conditionally set a header? I just tested this and it redirects when `param=one`, `param=two` and when the query string is empty, so seems to do what you're asking

Comment: I see, so you are also setting the header based on the environment variable. This still works for me when testing this configuration. Perhaps you have some other rules that are conflicting?

Comment: Thats what i mean - i don't see the header line `index, follow` in the response. These rules are first in htaccess - could it be, that rules, which come after, cause confilct too?

Comment: It's possible. What happens if you change the flags to `[E=INDEX_HEADER:1,L]`? And which version of Apache are you running?

Comment: `!.+` (not something) is the same as simply `^$` (nothing). Presumably, you have a `RewriteEngine On` directive somewhere?! (Except that you've included the redundant `<IfModule>` wrappers - making it "look" complete - but omitted a directive that is required.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you have a (negative) match when a string is present, but `.*` will match *zero or more* characters, you need to make sure you have *one or more*. Therefore changing to the below should work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteRule ...
```

This will match when the query string is equal to `Not (one_or_more_characters)`, i.e. it is nothing/empty

Comment: My case is to match urls with a special kind of query string or urls without any query string. So finally i will need something like:`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^param=(one|two)$ [OR] RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+`, to catch anything like param=three (or other), and urls without parameter.

Comment: @ChillyBang "to catch anything like param=three (or other)" - eh? What you posted does the opposite... it won't "catch anything like param=three (or other)"?!

Comment: Although you'd never write `!.+` (ie. _not something_), you would simply write `^$` (ie. _nothing_). (Or you could just make the preceding pattern optional.)